# Can I write data safely to a RAID-1 ARRAY while it is resyncing?

Tags: raid, sync, mdadm

Will the files be in all drives on the array when the sync is complete? 

What if a disk fails while sync is in progress?

Comment: From my research, "One can directly start using it while mdadm resyncs the array in the background." Now is this software or hardware RAID, etc. If it's software RAID you can check the process by `$ cat /proc/mdstat`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can safely write to any degraded RAID array and not lose any data, that's a standard RAID feature
- If a disk fails during sync, well it matters which disk that failed. If it was the resync target, who cares, it'll just resync from the master again. If it was the master then the RAID 1 has failed however that member still has the most up to date copy of the data. So if it's a transient error your data is probably fine, the system reboots and resync attempts to continue, if it's not then you've exceeded the protections provided by RAID 1 and have now lost data
- No RAID is a substitute for regular backups aka duplicity or plain old rsync.

Comment: I like bullet three =) You got my vote!

Answer (score 0):

If one of the disk fails then it will ruin your whole RAID setup, if the disk were to fail, then you will have to setup your whole RAID over again, so on that note, if at all possible, do not attempt to write file to the disk while in sync.

Comment: Do you mean to say "while syncing" instead of "while in sync"? "In sync" means that "synchronisation has completed", which is probably the opposite of what you meant to say.